# Is it possible to get the current line of the subtitle with libvlc?

Tags: c++, libvlc, video-subtitles

I want to be able to get the current showing text of the subtitle, possibly as a string. Is this possible?

If possible it would also be nice to get all of the text from the subtitles, not only the current line.

If not possible, is there maybe a library that can do this? I want to be able to show a video, and have the subtitles as selectable text.

As a side note i am using C++ and Qt.

Thanks in advance.